# Can not insert data ino table

Tags: c#-4.0

```
`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        TextBox7.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString();
    }` protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ASHISH;Initial Catalog=esaote;Integrated Security=True");
        string q = "insert into info(c_name,c_address, machine, s_version, email,i_ date,due_date) values(@c_name, @c_address, @machine, @s_version, @email, @i_date,@due_date)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_name", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_address", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_version", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_date",TextBox6.Text );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due_date", TextBox7.Text);
        //string due_date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).ToShortDateString();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("<script language='javascript'>alert('due date is'" + TextBox7.Text + ")</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.Write(exp.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

the catch block is giving incorrect syntax near date exception. i have changed i_date in the last cmd.parameter... to due_date. all the attributes in table have same name as given.i am not able to find a sol. also have converted the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here:

insert into info(c_name,c_address, machine, s_version, email,**i_ date**,due_date)

should be:

```
insert into info(c_name,c_address, machine, s_version, email,i_date,due_date)
```